# count within union query

Tags: mysql, union

I've never done a count withing a union query and am running into issues getting it done correctly.

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (
      SELECT vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code, count(*) as countv
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
      WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()
      GROUP BY vg.vertrekluchthaven

    UNION  

      SELECT vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code, count(*) as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
      WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()
      GROUP BY vg.aankomstluchthaven
   ) vg

INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON  lh.luchthavenID = vg.code
GROUP BY vg.code
ORDER BY lh.luchthavencode;
```

Ultimately I'm looking to figure out how to get a count for each code that is in each of the union queries. When I run the code, I get a count for the countv, but I don't get any kind of counta.

This is what I'm looking at obtaining:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
| CODE  |   Name    | count v   | count a   |  
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
| AMS   | LONG NAME |     5     |     8     |  
| MSP   | LONG NAME |     5     |     2     |   
| WAS   | LONG NAME |     2     |     0     | 
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the two counts in different columns, so they can be kept separate when grouping. Then use `MAX()` to get the non-zero count of each.

```
SELECT code, name, MAX(countv) countv, MAX(counta) counta
FROM (
      SELECT vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code, count(*) as countv, 0 as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
      WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()
      GROUP BY vg.vertrekluchthaven

    UNION  

      SELECT vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code, 0 as countv, count(*) as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
      WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()
      GROUP BY vg.aankomstluchthaven
   ) vg

INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON  lh.luchthavenID = vg.code
GROUP BY vg.code
ORDER BY lh.luchthavencode;
```

Comment: that's what I was missing. this worked perfectly. thank you so much for the help. I never thought about needing a second column for the opposite column.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining the result of your union query with 'tbl_luchthaven'. Maybe there is no record for one of your codes there, so no rows would be displayed for given code in final result set.